# When Google removes malicious apps from their Play Store, are users notified?

Tags: malware, google, google-apps

[This Check Point Research article](https://research.checkpoint.com/simbad-a-rogue-adware-campaign-on-google-play/) describes over 200 malicious apps on the Google Play Store that were downloaded over 100 million times.  Google has now removed the apps from their Play Store.

But what happens to the millions of people who have this software on their Android devices?  Are they somehow notified by Google?  Does Google automatically offer to uninstall the software for them?

Or are millions of users left with malicious apps on their Android devices?

Answer (score 3):

By default, no. This would require Google to sniff the apps in your phone, in which they should ask your permission to do so.

However, there is this:

[Google Play Protect](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2812853?hl=en)

> How Google Play Protect works
>
> Google Play Protect checks apps when you install them. It also
>   periodically scans your device. If it finds a potentially harmful app,
>   it might:
>
> Warn you. If an app is detected that may be harmful to your device,
>   you’ll get a notification. To remove the app, tap Uninstall on the
>   notification. Google Play Protect might also disable the app to keep
>   it from running until you uninstall it.
>
> Remove the app automatically.
>   In some cases, if a harmful app has been detected, you may get a
>   notification saying the app was removed.