# Are malware apps that were removed from Google Play Store also automatically removed from devices?

Tags: google-play-store

I have this question. I have read in the news "these 80 malware apps have been removed from Google Play Store".

Should I check my phone if I have one of them installed?
Or do they get removed automatically?

Comment: If it is malware then it is also removed from the connected devices, but I would assume that removing from PlayStore and removing from devices are two independent tasks but usually they are executed together.

Comment: Of course this would be the best. Did that happen to you or is this just your guess?

Comment: I don't install many apps, so chance to hit malware is pretty low. If an app is malicious removing it from store and devices is the only way it makes sense. Otherwise it would be careless by Google.

Comment: Related: [When Google removes malicious apps from their Play Store, are users notified?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208960/44325), [What happens when Google decides an app is "bad"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248990/44325)