# What happens when Google decides an app is "bad"?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, security, google, uninstallation

An Android 7 (Nougat) device that hadn't been used in a while (perhaps a few months) was recently turned on.  That device has Nova Launcher Pro installed.  It does not have external (microSD card) storage.

I noticed that one of the launcher's folders had a couple empty spots.  I don't recall deleting any apps, nor any icons from the launcher's folders. I don't remember exactly which apps were in those folders.

When Google Play Protect is disabled, I'm wondering if Google has the power (and legal authority, but that's a bigger question) to simply remove apps from Android devices if they deem those apps to be "bad".  By *"bad"*, I simply mean they crash too often, contain malware, violate user's privacy expectations, violate Google's Terms & Conditions, or something along those lines.

Note that all apps on that device were installed from Google's Play Store or from F-Droid (via it's primary repository).  Google Play Protect was not enabled.  Although Google does have a bad history of enabling functions/permissions that the user explicitly disabled, Google Play Protect does show itself as *disabled* on that device.

Comment: Have you ensured that you don't have these apps disabled?

Comment: @Firelord Yes,  There are *no* newly disabled apps.  Thanks for considering that possibility.

Comment: Related: [Are malware apps that were removed from Google Play Store also automatically removed from devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248617/44325)